# FTP Connect api Strange behaviour in android works only for hardcoded string but fails for String retrived from editText

Tags: android, ftp, ftp-client

connect works fine for Hardcoded String, 
if i get the string from EditText i am getting exception
like no route to host
I am Running the below  code in a thread

```
     FTPClient ftpclient = null;
     boolean status = false;
     final String ipaddress = edittext.gettext.tostring();
     try {
            ftpclient = new FTPClient();
```

> ftpclient.connect(ipaddress, 21); //works perfect
>                   ftpclient.connect(,21);//doesn't work
>                   //but both strings have same value.

```
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpclient.getReplyCode())) {
                if (ftpclient.login(usrname, passwd)) {
                    ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftpclient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    String data = getFilePath(filesize);
                   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                    String filestr = deviceId + Long.toString((new File(data)).length()) + "Bytes.txt";
                    Log.d("BLTtest", " filename: " + filestr);
                    boolean result = ftpclient.storeFile(filestr, in);
                    in.close();
                    if (result) {
                        status = true;
                        Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                    } else Log.v("upload result", "failed to upload");
                    //ftpclient.deleteFile(filestr);
                    ftpclient.logout();
                    ftpclient.disconnect();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return status;
        } finally {
            ftpclient.disconnect();
        }
```

### Logcat:

06-25 17:50:43.763  11106-11419/com.example.ftptest W/System.err﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /94.74.194.126 (port 21): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
06-25 17:50:43.763  11106-11419/com.example.ftptest W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)

Comment: You aren't specifying the port when you connect with the edittext

Comment: I tried even by giving port number still code doesn't work

Comment: Why not use ipaddress = edittext.gettext().toString() and call ipaddress in ftpclient.connect? Share the logcat if won't work

Comment: I changed ipaddress = edittext.gettext().toString() ; even know it is not working here i am sharing the logcat

Comment: LogCat says you are connecting to /94.74.194.126 and would be 94.74.194.126 debug and check if the string is changing in other part of the code.

Comment: Also, you can use ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ipaddress));